# What is "MMI Group" app?

Tags: applications, samsung

On my Samsung Galaxy Tab A, there is an app in the app settings called "MMI Group" and it takes lots of permissions. When researching, lots of users also have this app that takes lots of permissions, so it could be some test to see if all the permissions work or something, but it seems VERY sketchy and you can only force stop, that's it. But when researching, someone else said they contacted support and it was not a preinstalled app which is extremely sketchy. I have scanned my tablet with Malwarebytes though and I don't install sketchy things.

So, when looking, someone found the app on phones in the store, so I think it's just some weird app that gets installed a lot and maybe it's from the Google Play Store or Google, I don't know.

But the point is you can't uninstall or stop the app from using permissions, and it says that the app is needed for the system.

Comment: It is a system app coming preinstalled on many devices (especially Samsung's). Probably meant to deal with MMI codes, see eg [this article](https://www.geekinstructor.com/2020/07/fix-connection-problem-or-invalid-mmi-code.html) for some background.

Comment: I found the following information on MMI Group and I'm still puzzled as to why it's on my phone: https://www.linkedin.com/company/mmi-group-it-holding-company

Answer (score 1):

According to [Samsung Support Chat](https://r2.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-M/Am-I-safe-from-the-app-I-have-mentioned-named-quot-MMIGroup-quot/td-p/5607500),

> Sylvie
> This is a pre-installed app then which is included with device firmware.
>
> Sylvie
> It is actually a Samsung Electronics app used for syncing devices at home so you can control everything with your phone.
>
> Sylvie
> The pre installed apps which are included with the firmware can't be uninstalled.

---

According to [OP's 2nd revision of the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/233665/2) (with copyedit),

> When I went on Malwarebytes, I discovered that it said:
>
> 1. It's a system app
> 2. *Updated: Dec 31, 2008*
> 3. This date is the same for automation test, some priv. something, and things like what's new, media storage, and lots of others.
>
> In conclusion:
>
> This is a pre-installed app. I don't know why someone said the customer support said it didn't, there is a company called MMI group and I think the app is some kind of test or something. It is pretty sketchy, but Malwarebytes is fine with it.