# How to disable, delete, or block MMI Group?

Tags: applications, samsung

I noticed an MMI program in my files. It will not allow me to delete, block, or disable.

How do I disable, delete or block MMI Group?

Comment: Files where? Please show a screenshot of the location.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it alone, is the advice on other forums.

> That's a Samsung specific system app. You can't remove or disable it from the UI. Please consult Samsung for more information about it.

From google.support.

> This is a pre-installed app, idk why someone said the customer support said it didn't, there is a company called MMI group and I think the app is some kind of test or something but it is pretty sketchy but malwarebytes is fine with it

From [Another post on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233665)